# Why does a removable singularity 0 become a pole as w varies in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-it(w-w_0)}-e^{-it(w+w_0)}}{4t\pi i}$dt

Tags: complex-analysis

Background: this is the fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(2\pi t/T)}{t}$ using residues, and the convention $\mathcal{F}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\int f e^{-iwt}dt$

When $w>w_0$ the contour is closed in the lower half plane for both $\frac{e^{-it(w-w_0)}-e^{-it(w+w_0)}}{4t\pi i}$ because the exponent of e is positive at the same time $\frac{1}{4\pi i}(-\pi i--\pi i)=0$. Thus the residues cancel, which makes sense because zero is a removable singularity.The same goes for $w<-w_0$. When $-w_0<w<w_0$ the residue from the upper hemisphere minus the negative hemisphere residue add. Why is it no longer a removable singularity? The taylor series of $\frac{ti(-w+w_0)+[ti(-w+w_0)]^2\dots-ti(-w-w_0)+[ti(-w-w_0)]^2\dots}{t}$ still has a removable singularity.

Second question:
Why is it wrong to calculate $\mathcal{F}(\frac{sin(t)}{t})$ as the imaginary part $Im[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-iwt}\frac{e^{it}}{t}dt]$ Which yields incorrectly $\begin{cases} 1/2 &w<1\\
-1/2&w>1
\end{cases}$

Besides saying that it gives the wrong interval, what rule is broken yielding the wrong answer.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the exponent is positive or negative, does it?  For purposes of computing the residue, isn't it annihilated either way?  So the residue will always be $\frac{1}{4\pi i} - \frac{1}{4\pi i} = 0$

Comment: No, $|w|<w_0$ the two residues add because one contour closes in the l.h.p and the other in the u.h.p. so subtracting gives addition.

Comment: bonus question : how do you compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(at)}{t}$ with the residue theorem ?

Comment: Depending on the convention used $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ vs $1/2\pi$ you just add the residues as above for $-\alpha<w<\alpha$ to get pi/2. Most tables use the form not as above I think$

Comment: Double checking a PDE book something might be off. $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ when $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is the convention convention.

Comment: Found my error. Forgot to cancel pi. So 1/2?